# XenApp Citrix Server

Tags: xenapp

Recently we have noticed that on our XenApp Citrix 6.X server it sometimes fails to launch applications on the web interface. When I login to the server internally I can see that the users have been logging in, closing the session then attempting again.

I have monitored a user logging into the server and note they instantly go into a "Disconnected" status.It almost appears as though the server accepts the login, then instantly orphans the session into a disconnected state. Here was a live example of where it required 4 sessions to successfully launch a published application:

```
User 1 - Disconnected
User 1 - Disconnected
User 1 - Connected
User 1 - Disconnected
```

Now I have tested this on multiple computers running different OS, different browsers, different users - all result in the same instant.

We find the general "fix" is to simply kick all sessions of the user on the local server and then everything behaves. Undoubtedly upgrading to a newer version of XenApp would assist; but this is costly and at present outweighs the benefits.

I have had a look on the logs of this Windows Server 2008R2 (from memory) and cannot see any warning for services or applications. I have not been able to find any articles that point the blame at Windows Updates etc. that could cause this.

Has anyone else had this issue, and how so was it fixed if so?

Comment: Does the symptom happen with the receiver? What receiver version you use too.

Comment: The end user logs into the web-portal and then launches the application. The client has their own Citrix Receiver installed on their PC. Are you referencing this, or another module? I would need to login to the server to clarify. [Side Note: Not too familiar with XenApp, sorry]

Comment: Sorry, iam on my phone, didnt gave much detail too. I mean, the portal push an online plugin, or java plugin, but they are usually not up to date. For a test I would go install like the version 3.4, or the last version and do a test after, to bypass the webportal.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I can test the "XenApp Receiver" on some client PCs. Unfortunately there is an explicit version required for other applications. I will do this and try. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect. By the way, if you need a older client for the PNA function, you can tweak the receiver to support old farm, push .ica to connect to other farm, etc.. there is multiple workaround possible in citrix :)